# Qt: Change icon in a QFileInfo object

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

- My foremost question is:

How do I set/change the file icon in a QFileInfo object?
If you look at my code,  `Qlist<QFileInfo>` lists the icon of all my folders in my home directory as gnome-fs-directory. Which means, QFileInfo lists even my desktop folder's icon as plain gnome-fs-directory.

But I want Desktop to have QFileIconProvider::Desktop as icon.

- Which consequently leads to the 2nd question:

Is QFileInfo the appropriate class to use to find out the icon that QFileSystemModel would use?

- Which leads to the 3rd question:

Why did my QDir not pass QFileSystemModel a QFileInfo list with the appropriate icon role for Desktop?

- So the ultimate question is, what do I have to do to ensure QFileSystemModel uses the appropriate icon role, when listing itself in a tree view or list view?

Code to find out the file icon of each folder in the home folder:

```
void MainWindow::fileIconInfo(QFileSystemModel *model)
{
    QFileIconProvider *iconprov = model->iconProvider();

    QFileInfoList fileInfoList = QDir::home().entryInfoList();
    QFileInfoList::Iterator i;

    foreach (QFileInfo fi, fileInfoList){

        if (fi.fileName() == QString("Desktop"))
            /*change the icon to QFileIconProvider::Desktop*/;

        //the following line indicates all my icons are gnome-fs-directory!!*/
        std::cout << iconprov->icon(fi).name().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is my main window:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    fileSystemTree(ui->listView);
    fileSystemTree(ui->treeView);
}
```

Setting the model for the view:

```
void MainWindow::fileSystemTree(QAbstractItemView *view) {
    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
    model->setRootPath(QDir::homePath());

    view->setModel(model);
    view->setRootIndex(model->index(QDir::homePath()));

    fileIconInfo(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are describing is caused by the fact that QFileIconProvider is detecting that you use Gnome, and the is using Gtk style - no matter what. Could you try to start some other desktop environment and see if problem remains? If it does then I am right and only thing you can do is to subclass QFileSystemModel and change QIcon returned from data method - but this is quite crude and non-flexible solution.

Comment: I built and ran my project on Vista and all the diverse icons showed up. Which means that Nokia does not give gnome any importance.

Comment: I dont think that they give it no importance - i rather think that either gnome fails to recognize what icons it should return, or qt is asking wrong way... anyway, it seems like a bug to me...